# CodeIgniter base_url() is returning Windows path in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis-7, codeigniter-3

CodeIgniter 3.0.3 on IIS7 intranet server: I'm migrating an application from 2.x and following the [upgrade procedure](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html).

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://myIntranet.myDomain.com/myAppDir/';
```

If I display `$base_url()` on my webpage I get

```
base_url: http://myIntranet.myDomain.com/myAppDir/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myAppDir\application\
```

i.e., It's giving me `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myAppDir\application\` as part of the URL.

Access control (web.config) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
                    <match url="index.php|robots.txt|images|test.php" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've read through multiple posts with similar problems on this site but haven't found exactly the same problem.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix?

Comment: Can you show how do you call it (I.E. controller and view code)? Is there some kind of middleware (helper/core class extended by controller etc)? What is output of `site_url()`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. As I started to get `site_url()` I realised that the Windows path is coming from APPPATH. I'll see if I can find where that's set.

Comment: Still working on it. It seems someone else had the problem: http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-61445.html.

Comment: I removed APPPATH from any links in my templates and I seem to be making progress. It's not documented in the upgrade procedure despite the recommendation on the forum link. Thank you again.

Comment: `APPPATH` is never meant to be close with publicly related content. It is against security logic. Check all your view files and remove any path/string related to `application` or `system`.

Comment: OK, I'll check that.